# What design pattern is this code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What kind of a design pattern is this and what is the significance of using this closure?

```
(function(){
    // my code here
}).call(this);
```

#### Edit

Then what is the difference between the above code and the following as the `this` keyword will still refer to the same object in both the ways.

```
(function(){
    // my code here
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to hone my search skills

Comment: Your question is still identical to the linked one.

Answer (score 7):

Thats an immediately invoked function expression.

More info here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

The purpose is to run code immediately while protecting scope (so variables declared within don't leak out to the global scope.

#### Update

`call` sets the value of `this` for the function its being applied on. Without it, the value is set to the window object, with it there it is set to the outer scope.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @zzzzBov independently put up the same link.  Thanks though.

Comment: Can you check the edit I made